# How do you expand a function on a sphere as a series?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

For a function on a circle $f(\theta)$ you can Fourier expand this in terms of $sin$ and $cos$ functions. For a function on a sphere $f(\theta,\sigma)$ is there an equivalent expansion? Perhaps in terms of spherical harmonics?

Comment: Yes, spherical harmonics on the sphere are analogous to trig functions on the circle.

Comment: I think you said it yourself: [spherical harmonics expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Spherical_harmonics_expansion)

Comment: Yeah. I think it was a silly question